# Neo4j batch importer NotFoundException

Tags: neo4j

I'm consistently running into a NotFoundException when using the [batch importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20) to read large nodes and relationship files. I've used the importer successfully before with an even larger dataset, but I've rewritten the way I generate the two files, and I'm trying to figure out why it now throws an error.

**The problem**

It seems to read the nodes file and then throws an error near the start of the rels file, stating that it cannot find a node. I believe this is because it hasn't really imported all the nodes. It reports importing only half of the nodes in nodes.tsv (2.1m of 4.6m total).

*Things I've checked:*

1. The node numbers in nodes.tsv are sequential and continuous (0 to ~4.5m)
2. The node that throws the exception appears in both files (including as both source and target in rels.tsv)
3. I can successfully import a smaller subset of my data (~80k nodes) using the same tsv generator script
4. Even though the relationships are not sorted on target (only on source), the smaller subset does not throw this exception

*The insert command:*

```
./import.sh wiki.db nodes.tsv rels.tsv
```

**Error message**

```
Using Existing Configuration File
.....................
Importing 2129648 Nodes took 6400 seconds 

Total import time: 6404 seconds 

Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: id=3608148
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.getNodeRecord(BatchInserterImpl
.java:1215)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.createRelationship(BatchInserte
rImpl.java:777)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.importRelationships(Importer.java:154)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.doImport(Importer.java:232)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.main(Importer.java:83)
```

**The files**

*nodes.tsv (4578730 lines)*

```
node    name    l:label degrees
0   Stroud_railway_station  Page    21
1   ATP–ADP_translocase Page    38
2   Pedro_Hernández_Martínez    Page    12
3   Christopher_Lowther Page    4
4   Cloncurry_River Page    10
5   Neil_Kinnock    Page    147
6   Free_agent_(business)   Page    10
7   Christian_Hilt  Page    27
8   2009_Riviera_di_Rimini_Challenger   Page    27
```

*rels.tsv (113322480 lines)*

```
start   end type
0   3608148 LINKS_TO
0   870126  LINKS_TO
0   1516248 LINKS_TO
0   3493391 LINKS_TO
0   3034096 LINKS_TO
0   1421544 LINKS_TO
0   2808745 LINKS_TO
0   1872783 LINKS_TO
0   1673612 LINKS_TO
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm seems to be a problem with your CSV file, did you try to run CSVKit or similar on it?

Perhaps you can narrow down the issue by bisecting the nodes.csv and finding the offending line?

Also try to use the opencsv parser by enabling quotes in your batch.properties

https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20#csv-experimental

batch_import.csv.quotes=true

Or flip it to false. Perhaps you have stray single our double quotes in your text? If so then please quote it.

Comment: `batch_import.csv.quotes=true` solved the issue. There must have been stray double quotes in the large file, but not the smaller subset.